# can I use a variable, generated in foreach loop in another following foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach

That script uses gci, to  get the latestfile out of many folders and subfolders. From every sub-subfolder the latestfile is in the variable $latestfile. As a next step I want to get via foreach loop, for every latestfile the parent folder. It seems problematic to use the $latestfile variable in another foreach loop.

This code works:

```
#Copying with variable, get the latest file, descending take  first, timestamp
$latestfile = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |
     Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1).FullName
}
echo $latestfile
```

the output:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.931\202307\16\0238\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.932\202307\16\0251\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.940\202312\17\1204\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.941\202312\17\1125\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.942\202312\23\1107\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.943\202312\23\1106\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.944\202312\19\1116\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.945\202311\25\1238\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.946\201812\23\1536\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.947\202312\17\1101\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.948\202312\17\1108\fiscal.xml
C:\Users\User\Documents\VersandvorbMitDaten\Versandvorbereitung\Journ\MYBOFFID.950\201912\22\1015\fiscal.xml
```

Next I want to get every parent folder via foreach loop:

```
#Get Parent folder, create variable $parent
$parent = ForEach-Object {(Get-Item $latestfile).Directory.Parent
}
echo $parent
```

gives me an error message:

```
Get-Item : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Path" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
In C:\Users\User\Documents\ps\foreach_gci_latestfile.ps1:11 Zeichen:37
+ $parent = ForEach-Object {(Get-Item $latestfile).Directory.Parent
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

Thank You for Your help

Comment: ```$latestfile``` is an *array* containing the latest filename from each directory - you need to *pipe* this into ```foreach-object``` and then use ```Get-Item $_ …``` to iterate over the file names.

Answer (score 2):

As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) stated in comments, the resulting array from the previous step (`$latestfile`) is what **you pipe into `ForEach-Object`** then you can reference each pipeline item via `$_`:

```bash
$latestfile = Get-ChildItem -Path 'path\to\Journ' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -Last 1
}

$latestfile | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Item $_).Directory.Parent
}
```

However this process can be simplified if you include the parent in the previous step:

```bash
$latestfile = Get-ChildItem -Path 'path\to\Journ' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
        Select-Object FullName, @{ N = 'Parent'; E = { $_.Directory.Parent } } -Last 1
}
```

This will create an array of objects with 2 properties each, the `.FullName` of the file and the `DirectoryInfo` instance representing the parent directory of the file's directory. An, if you wanted to get all parents it would be as simple as:

```
$latestfile.Parent
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a variable generated in one foreach loop in another following foreach loop in PowerShell. However, there are a few considerations you need to keep in mind:

```
# Define an array or collection outside the loops
$items = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# First foreach loop
foreach ($item in $items) {
    Write-Output "Processing Item: $item"

    # Use the $item variable in the first loop
    # Second foreach loop

foreach ($anotherItem in $items) {
        Write-Output "Processing Another Item: $anotherItem based on $item"

    }
}
```

Comment: Thnk You very much for the wonderful help, I am testing...

Comment: This case is solved!!!!